# Pandas lookup within groupby dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, rolling-computation

I have the below df:

```
data={'Name':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
'Sales':['327','255','977','211','146','183','138','142','156','208','195','224','181','351','166','173','320','197','311','327','245','186','362','391','604','2320','2230','0','0'],
'Price':['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','60','61','62','63','64','65','66','67'],
'Second_highest_Sales':['','255','327','327','327','327','327','327','327','','195','208','208','224','224','224','320','320','320','327','327','','186','362','391','604','2230','2230','2230']}

data=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I am looking to get the corresponding 'price' for 'Second_highest_Sales' based on 'Sales' for each group (Name). The result would look like:

```
result={
'Name':['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','C','C','C','C','C','C'],
'Sales':['327','255','977','211','146','183','138','142','156','208','195','224','181','351','166','173','320','197','311','327','245','186','362','391','604','2320','2230','0','0'],
'Price':['10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','60','61','62','63','64','65','66','67'],
'Second_highest_Sales':['','255','327','327','327','327','327','327','327','','195','208','208','224','224','224','320','320','320','327','327','','186','362','391','604','2230','2230','2230'],
'2nd_Highest_Price':['','11','10','10','10','10','10','10','10','','31','30','30','32','32','32','37','37','37','40','40','','60','61','62','63','65','65','65']}

result=pd.DataFrame(result)
```

I tried with .shift() and .lookup() but get the index error on a groupby dataframe. Is there an easier way to do this instead of a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

I would

- Get the 'Second_highest_Sales' series removing empty values
- Retrieve corresponding Names
- re-index DataFrame by Names and Sales
- search Price on corresponding Names and Second_highest_Sales
- Fill the column with desired values where Second_highest_Sales are defined

It would be something like this on code

```
shs = data['Second_highest_Sales']
shs = shs[shs!='']
shs_names = data.iloc[shs.index]['Name']
prices = data.set_index(['Name','Sales']).loc[zip(shs_names, shs)]['Price']
result = data.copy()
result ['Second_highest_Price']=''
result.loc[shs.index,'Second_highest_Price'] = prices.values
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with merge

```
out = pd.merge(df,
                  df[['Name','Sales','Price']].\
                          rename(columns={'Sales':'Second_highest_Sales',
                                          'Price':'Second_highest_Prices'})
                 ,how='left')
   Name Sales Price Second_highest_Sales Second_highest_Prices
0     A   327    10                                        NaN
1     A   255    11                  255                    11
2     A   977    12                  327                    10
3     A   211    13                  327                    10
4     A   146    14                  327                    10
5     A   183    15                  327                    10
6     A   138    16                  327                    10
7     A   142    17                  327                    10
8     A   156    18                  327                    10
9     B   208    30                                        NaN
10    B   195    31                  195                    31
11    B   224    32                  208                    30
12    B   181    33                  208                    30
13    B   351    34                  224                    32
14    B   166    35                  224                    32
15    B   173    36                  224                    32
16    B   320    37                  320                    37
17    B   197    38                  320                    37
18    B   311    39                  320                    37
19    B   327    40                  327                    40
20    B   245    41                  327                    40
21    C   186    60                                        NaN
22    C   362    61                  186                    60
23    C   391    62                  362                    61
24    C   604    63                  391                    62
25    C  2320    64                  604                    63
26    C  2230    65                 2230                    65
27    C     0    66                 2230                    65
28    C     0    67                 2230                    65
```